# Natural Lie algebra structure on $\bigwedge\nolimits^2 \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: lie-algebras, multilinear-algebra

As vector spaces, the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ is isomorphic $\bigwedge\nolimits^2 \mathbb{R}^n$ with the isomorphism given on simple bivectors
$$\Phi: \bigwedge\nolimits^2 \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathfrak{so}(n): u \wedge v \mapsto \langle u, \cdot\rangle v - \langle v, \cdot \rangle u$$
and extended by bilinearity, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Does $\bigwedge\nolimits^2 \mathbb{R}^n$ a priori have any natural Lie algebra structure so that the above map is a Lie algebra isomorphism?

Trivially, we can use $\Phi$ to pullback the Lie bracket from $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ to $\bigwedge\nolimits^2 \mathbb{R}^n$, but this is a structure that is put by hand a posteriori.

Comment: I think the standard Lie algebra structure on $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is exactly the one you're describing.  The isomorphism $\Phi$ is a pretty natural one. Also, from a practical point of view, identifying $2$-forms with skew-symmetric matrices in this way is often quite helpful, both computationally and conceptually.

Comment: One observation is that $\bigwedge\nolimits^2 (\mathbb{R}^n)^* \simeq \left(\bigwedge\nolimits^2 \mathbb{R}^n\right)^* \simeq \operatorname{Hom}\left(\bigwedge\nolimits^2 \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}\right)$. On the other hand bilinear alternating maps $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ correspond to skew-symmetric matrices, so maybe the natural structure would rather be defined on the dual.